# Number of rotations

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

#### Task

Write a function or a program to find the number of rotations required by a wheel to travel a given distance, given its radius.

#### Rules

Input can be 2 positive rational numbers and can be taken in any convenient format.

Both inputs are of same unit.

**There must not be any digits 0-9 in your code.**

The output will be an integer (in case of float, round to infinity)

This is **code-golf** so shortest code wins

#### Examples

```
distance radius  output
10       1       2
50       2       4
52.22    4       3
3.4      0.08    7
12.5663  0.9999  3
```

Comment: You probably should add that digits are also forbidden in compiler options (or anywhere else): if you limit this constraint to code only, with gcc we can do something like `-DP=3.14` in compiler flags, that would define `P` as an approximation of pi, which is probably not what you intended

Answer (score 6):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
τ/╠ü
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//98i/6jqQsO7/n/39BAwZDL1EDBiMvUSM/ISMGEy1jPRMFAz8CCy9BIz9TMzBjIsQQCAA)

### Explanation

```
τ      Push tau (2*pi)
 /     Divide the first argument (total distance) by tau
  ╠    Reverse divide (computes (distance/tau)/radius)
   ü   Ceiling
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```java
a->b->-~(int)(a/b/Math.PI/'')
```

Contains unprintable `\u0002` between the single quotes.

Port of [*@jOKing*'s Perl 6 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176335/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY5Na8JAEIbBY37F3NwFM4nrBy22OZWCB6HgUTxMvuym6yaYiSCifz3dUkOOZk4vzPPAU9CZ/CL9aRNDdQ0b0vbqAdRMrBMo3Bcb1gbzxiasS4ufj/H2UTaxySaDmLXl7JCdoghyeG/Jj2I/8u9CW5aCgjjYEH/j1zoYj8ayXXkuoHKiC3h0nEudwtG1iS2ftD3s9kDyrxNge6k5O2LZMFbuxcaKHKmqzEVMw1R2M5Vy9Yxf9LwaxCtUqjPmQ4wZzjs@xPBlgDFVuFguZ7316u7fu3m39hc)

Comment: Is that the digit '1' in your code? I think that might not be allowed.

Comment: @ouflak Looks like it can be fixed like [this](https://tio.run/##jY5Na8JAEIbBY37F3NwFM4nrBy22OZWCB6HgUTxMvuym6yaYiSCifz3dUkOOZk4vzPPAU9CZ/CL9aRNDdQ0b0vbqAdRMrBMo3Bcb1gbzxiasS4ufj/H2UTaxySaDmLXl7JCdoghyeG/Jj2I/8u9CW5aCgjjYEH/j1zoYj8ayXXkuoHKiC3h0nEudwtG1iS2ftD3s9kDyrxNge6k5O2LZMFbuxcaKHKmqzEVMw1R2M5Vy9Yxf9LwaxCtUqjPmQ4wZzjs@xPBlgDFVuFguZ7316u7fu3m39hc).

Comment: @ouflak Woops, that was a pretty stupid mistake.. Using the unprintable so I don't use the digit `2`, and then just use digit `1`... Luckily Erik is indeed right that a simple negative unary has the same effect as `+1` (often used to get rid of parenthesis since the negative and unary have higher precedence than most other operators).

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

*-3 bytes tjanks to nwellnhof reminding me about tau*

```perl6
*/*/τ+|$+!$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0tfS/98i3aNiraiyn9rruLESoU0DUMDHUNNGMfUQMcIwTHSMzLSUTCBCxjrmegoGOgZWMBFDI30TM3MjEGilkCgaf0fAA)

Anonymous Whatever lambda that uses the formula `(a/b/tau).floor+1`. Tau is two times pi. The two anonymous variables `$` are coerced to the number `0`, which is used to floor the number `+|0` (bitwise or 0) and add one `+!$` (plus not zero).

Comment: _There must not be any digits 0-9 in your code._

Comment: @Titus I can't believe I forgot that. Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Are digits in exponents also allowed?

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, 9 bytes

Prompts for radius followed by distance:

```
⌈⎕÷○r+r←⎕
```

[Try it online!  Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6ukAihze/mh6d5F2EVAcyPsPlPmfxqVnYMFlrGcCAA)

Explanation:

```
○r+r←⎕ prompt for radius and double it and multiply by pie

⌈⎕÷ prompt for distance, divide by result above and take ceiling
```

Comment: [`⌈⎕÷○+⍨⎕`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6ukAihze/mh6t/aj3hVA9n@g@P80LkMuQwMA) works for 7 bytes.

Comment: @J.Sallé Thanks but unfortunately my ancient APL+WIN interpreter does not have the ⍨ operator

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```python
lambda l,r:l/(r+r)//math.pi+l/l
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcvLCsMgFATQfb7iQjcJCT6uJn1A/6QbSwkRNJGLm369bU2qsxrmMOEdl23FNN8fyRn/fBlwA90cb6mnjnNv4sKC7R13jfVhowi/KQWya4S5lQJyBpB76eAE2Px5LIyVdWVkiJl1ZVVYMX28BROXg8@FJbJxmlTm6zf7O30A)

---

- -2 bytes, thanks to flawr
- -1 byte, thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: Since inputs have been guaranteed to be both (strictly) positive and rational we never hit the edge-case of requiring an exact number of rotations, so I think we can do `l/(r+r)//pi+l/l` and save a byte.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
·/žq/î
```

Port of [*@flawr*'s Python 2 comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176328/number-of-rotations#comment424571_176329).
Takes the input in the order `radius`,`distance`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Hb9o/sK9Q@v@//fkMvQAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q9v/Qdv2j@wr1D6/7r/PfkMvQgMuIy9SAy4TL1EjPyIjLQM/AgstYzwTIsAQCLkMjPVMzM2MA).

**Explanation:**

```python
·         # Double the first (implicit) input
 /        # Divide the second (implicit) input by it
  žq/     # Divide it by PI
     î    # Ceil it (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/create_explanation.py), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
∞/π/ü
```

Semi-port of [*@flawr*'s Python 2 comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176328/number-of-rotations#comment424571_176329).
Takes the input in the order `radius distance`.

-1 byte because `ceil` builtin has just been added, replacing the `floor+1`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9Rxzz98w36h/f8/2@oYGjAZaRgasBlomBqpGdkxGWgZ2ChYKxnAmRYAoGCoZGeqZmZMQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞        # Double the first (implicit) input
 /       # Divide the second (implicit) input by it
  π/     # Divide it by PI
    ü    # Ceil (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 47 bytes

```php
<?=ceil($argv[++$i]/M_PI/(($b=end($argv))+$b));
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c16dfdd0af45e7222fabae2e6f68841537cbba34).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->l,r{(l/Math::PI/r+=r).ceil}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5Hp6haI0ffN7Ekw8oqwFO/SNu2SFMvOTUzp/Z/QWlJsUJatKGBjmEsF5RjaqBjhOAY6RkZ6ZjA@cZ6JjoGegYWcAFDIz1TMzNjoKAlEMT@BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Catholicon](https://github.com/okx-code/Catholicon), 8 bytes

```
ċ//ĊǓĊ`Ė
```

Explanation:

```
  /ĊǓĊ    divide the first input by the doubled second input
 /    `Ė  divide that by pi
ċ         ceil
```

New version (pi builtin made one byte, division parameters swapped), 5 bytes

```
ċ/π/Ǔ
```

Answer (score 2):

### **C, 46 bytes**

```
f(float a,float b){return ceil(a/(b+b)/M_PI);}
```

I'm new to PPCG, so I'm not sure wether I have to count other parts in the byte count, such as the

```
include <math.h>
```

needed for the ceil function, which will rise the count to **64 bytes**

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a nice first answer. Yes, you do need to count `#include` and the like towards your byte total. A link to an online test suite is always appreciated, here's one you are free to incorporate into your post: https://tio.run/##bY5BC4IwHMXP9Sn@FMGGc9OppRjdOwR9gCDmdDWYK2wdQvrqrSLp5Okdfj/eezI8Senn2kpzrxtYt8Kd6XkDjEEAcQ7VwzU3r5AyF@FAkF9WuO8ad@8syEYbJBiqggqz3XG/xeXTt0JbhKGfTq6dtk6h2aI@2BkBheKIQIxx@R3gIzz7cD7wdIxzyjmBdFCSESWhKYGIRvngrMZucJotl8nXK4riX/b0L6mMON18aNo3

Comment: @O.O.Balance Digits are not allowed in the code for this challenge ;)

Comment: @Annyo I knew I was forgetting something :(

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>10</strike> 9 bytes

```
>.@%o.@+:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYs7CoAwFAT7nGIRRERZns8PGojkLmIQGwtrzx7jZ6uZgd1jOB0hsJA40@cHfWVjaTKiCI4FalwW4TRmXbYDjSCg@bh/WH9WqibtPm3ZJRHK@N@U/TC0b5vS4g0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
Vt*/e
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Vt*%2Fe&i=10+++++++1%0A50+++++++2%0A52.22++++4%0A3.4++++++0.08%0A12.5663++0.9999&a=1&m=2)

```
Vt*   multiply by tau (2pi)
/     divide
e     ceiling
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>45</s> <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```c
f(d,r,R)float d,r;{R=ceil(d/r/'G'/'\n'*'q');}
```

A reasonable approximation of pi is 355/113. Since circumference C = 2 * r * PI, we can instead of pi use tau, which is then of course ~710/113. 710 happens to have the convenient factors 2 * 5 * 71, which is compactly expressed as `'G' * '\n'`. <s>We add one (`r/r`) to force rounding to infinity.</s>

Edit: My trick was too clever for its own good: it of course made it fail if the distance was a multiple of the circumference.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwEEXXzVcEoSQpMWp8tEW67t61G0kaEXy0qXQj/nrTRCt4FzOXwxlG@LUQxigsqaYFUe1QjdD2fCpu4tG0WAY6QHcUoLJHJ/RCJJ/NZ2gkrPEmw7VoAiZweOqmHxX2jmeWKPifsuw96kxtZew2ITmYAbAu7Kqmx8ttjaMQulAYLdtKFqYb5HvIGecOJjsYs2Q1QxZeNhhxlmZZ7ODVxj02X6Haqn4bv@1@)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

```julia
f(d,r)=cld(d/π,r+r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jRadI0zY5J0UjRf98g06RdpHmf4fijPxyhTQNQwMdQ00uGM/UQMcIiWekZ2SkY4IQMNYz0THQM7BAiBga6ZmamRkDRS2BQPM/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>39</s> 32 bytes

-7 bytes Thanks to Giuseppe

```r
function(d,r)ceiling(d/(r+r)/pi)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYZBDkAwEADvXrLLZrVbhIPXtEgTqabhJN5eag4zk3KO83oFe/ojgKOEt1387sMGroVUR98UIT45glaksYrQK5K/wiLUlTXcEauxrBbuh8GQ4ukD8ws)

I feel like this could definitely be golfed, but I am a bit lazy right now to do anything about it

Answer (score 2):

## [min](https://min-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```
/ tau / ceil int
```

Takes the distance and radius put on the stack in that order. Then divides by tau, rounds, and makes int.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 25 bytes

*-2 bytes using @flawr comment =D. -1 from @Kevin. -7 from @Shaggy*

```javascript
a=>b=>-~(a/(b+b)/Math.PI)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcy7DoIwFIDhGZ@i4zkx9AqoQ9kdTHyFFsFLGkqkOPrqFXVQ6z9/@S/mZsbmeh5Cbo1tXd77Qxs7HY2ura7zOxgGdmmR7Uw40f0WY@P70buWOn@EDgRHEIiEZFnGGPFTGKZA5OJXlbOSf6pIlaRSIhRv@HEqcYoWCJzydQpXCRSSllWlnngz9@Jf2/gA)

Comment: Just `a=>b=>Math.ceil(a/(b+b)/Math.PI)` is 32 bytes. :)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zcy7DoIwFIDhGZ@i4zkx9AqoQ9kdTHyFFsFLGkqkOPrqFXVQ6z9/@S/mZsbmeh5Cbo1tXd77Qxs7HY2ura7zOxgGdmmR7Uw40f0WY@P70buWOn@EDgRHEIiEZFnGGPFTGKZA5OJXlbOSf6pIlaRSIhRv@HEqcYoWCJzydQpXCRSSllWlnngz9@Jf2/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
÷÷ØPHĊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdiCcEeBxpOv////Geib/DfQMLAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <strike>61</strike> <strike>58</strike> <strike>57</strike> 49 bytes

```lua
function(s,r)return math.ceil(s/(r+r)/math.pi)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjBCoAgDADQX@m4kSgVCR36mDAlwZbM@f0resdX@qFp19QpSH4ImmHkKJ1puA@5bIi5QHPAI6P7p2aMdGrlTAIJptmu3i/Gbh9EfQE)

*Thanks to KirillL. -8 bytes.*

Comment: I don't know much Lua (so maybe it's still too long), but it appears to be shorter as a function: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcjBCoAgDADQX@m4kSgVCR36mDAlwZbM@f0resdX@qFp19QpSH4ImmHkKJ1puA@5bIi5QHPAI6P7p2aMdGrlTAIJptmu3i/Gbh9EfQE)

Comment: @KirillL., I'm still learning the rules here. The OP's challenge is pretty open on the input. So my question is, would we have to count your program call() against the byte count? If not, your's definitely shaves off a nice chunk.

Comment: A quite common style of submission here is an anonymous function (so that we don't have to count the name, unless it is recursive), which outputs by its return value. The footer section with function calls and actual printing to console is then basically used for visualizing the results and doesn't count towards your score. BTW, you may add more of the OP's test examples to the footer, so that they can be conveniently viewed all at once. Note that in some cases a full program may actually turn out to be golfier!

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 7 bytes

```
/MT/V c
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=L01UL1YgYw==&input=MTAKMQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
import'dart:math';f(a,b)=>(a/(b+b)/pi).ceil();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxNCsMgFATgfU/houB71Bo1Jv2R5i7aNERo0hDchZzdCm5anN3wDdPbNcTop@WzBtqncp9sGKkZwDKHjw5sBe7ksFo88ufLvwFNnKyfAbcDIcvq5wD0uA0gBZO4k3NHFEXzb41gKpsuTXGlmM5cF1xzzQQX1@yXwqXiTdvWaXNL@XnZ4xc)

- -1 byte thanks to @Shaggy

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZcxNCsMgFATgfU/houB71Bo1Jv2R5i7aNERo0hDchZzdCm5anN3wDdPbNcTop@WzBtqncp9sGKkZwDKHjw5sBe7ksFo88ufLvwFNnKyfAbcDIcvq5wD0uA0gBZO4k3NHFEXzb41gKpsuTXGlmM5cF1xzzQQX1@yXwqXiTdvWaXNL@XnZ4xc)

Answer (score 1):

**Haskell, 25 bytes**

```
f d r=ceiling(d/(r+r)/pi)
```

Comment: You can define an operator `(!)` instead of `f` and use `ceiling$` instead of `ceiling(..)`which saves you 3 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PctBCsIwEIXhvaeYQheKNk0madVFj@AJRCTYooNpCKn3j2Wi@VcPPt7LLu/JuZTGKg6PiRz5Zz2227iPuzZQmi15GGC24XKHEMl/NgBXUBK4ClQeTQO4ygG6IljEZEGByGKKaBYtzO8jhTxlObIoFF3fa5bz2v9zS@kL "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 36 bytes

```
(lambda(a b)(ceiling(/ a(+ b b)pi)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7dCoJAEIXve4qDEM0QbLr@ZBDRq6yuxYK6ouvtvrqNRNDcnO8MA9@0vVumjV5@HkxAQGLdEszYdpiNdesC@DVMa4jHhA/Uez9BbkEWM8ONOBFlKTIGlSn0HlppjUIoVwVSldaCmVZlVeVSbzLMsB5/zlg/79HGB@L1B@UXRAtRgTbqzdBYQwYNU9u53o1vusDQGY2sJsfM2/6VxAc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 50 bytes

```
proc N d\ r {expr ceil($d/(($r+$r)*acos(-$r/$r)))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcuxDsIgFEbh/T7FPzCARgq0NPoSfQF1aKCDCabktiYmDc@ODJ7tG84eUq2Z14AJ8QHGsXwzIyyvJEXspBR8FqxOc1g3eRHcNShVanrP@T@QNbDkDRx5p53DQL0eYLS5knXaj2PfcGtRwZE/@4b7BBEh@FnqDw)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 53 bytes

```
proc N d\ r {expr ceil($d/(($r+$r)*acos(-[incr i])))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcsxDoMgGIbhnVN8AwO0kQKKaS/hBayDAQcSWsmvTZoYzk4d@m7P8O4@1Zpp9RgQniAcyzcT/BKT4OEmBKcrJ3mZ/bqJZoxvT4iTlLLU9Jrz/2FGwzCnYZmzylp0rFUdtNJ3Zqxyfd@eeJyxgiN/9g3jAB7AaSr1Bw)

Lack of a pi constant or function makes me lose the golf competition!

Comment: Do I need to remove the .0 at end of each output? It would make me consume more bytes!

Comment: `[incr i]` is quite clever but I think you can use `$d/$d` or `$r/$r` instead.

Comment: Saved some bytes thanks to @david's idea!

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <strike>53</strike> <strike>52</strike> 51 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @mazzy
-1 byte after I realized I don't need a semicolon after the `param()` block

```
param($d,$r)($a=[math])::ceiling($d/($r+$r)/$a::pi)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVFR6VIU0Ml0TY6N7EkI1bTyio5NTMnMy8dKKWvoVKkDZTWV0m0sirI1Pz/HwA)

Takes input from two commandline parameters, distance `-d` and radius `-r`.

Comment: ? `param($d,$r);($a=[math])::ceiling($d/($r+$r)/$a::pi)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

```
(d,r)->-d/(r+r)\-Pi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjLDsIgEIXhV5l0BXEGYXqJLuwzdF9ZEJsaEmImxEV9eoSe1fcfCTnSW8oODyhqw6xppu2q8iXrJy2xBJH0UwfQDJLj51vZtejgFVJSO8KhNcK6OovgfNVYwSfYMCMMzb0ZEKyxtxaOzThNfTvudd7r8gc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 22 bytes

```
f(d,r)=ceil(d/π(r+r))
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y4tjadxsah)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (Babel Node), 23 bytes

```
s=>r=>-~(s/2/r/Math.PI)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcy9DsIgFEDhuT4FI3colEtbdaC7g4mvQCv1J6Q0hTr66lh1UPHMX85V37TvpssY8la3xuaDO5rYq@hVM6kmv1PPkU98r8OZHXYQOzd4Zw2z7kR7KgqgAoCQLMs4J24O4xwIrn5VtSj8U2WqkCECLd/w42TiJCuBFqzYpHCdQIGsqmv5xNulF//axgc)

Comment: *There must not be any digits 0-9 in your code.*

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 50 bytes

```clj
(fn[a b](int(Math/ceil(/ a Math/PI(count"  ")b))))
```

An anonymous function that accepts two integers `a` and `b` as arguments: the distance and the wheel's radius, respectively.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDBjsIgFEX3fsVNVzRpkNJWZ@IXTDImLtyZWdAKaQ0BR2F@vz5rZoGpC9@O8zgnhM76U7zocWTGHRTaHza4wLYq9MtOD5YtoTCddl@s89GFDMjyNqcZ2VEbGLxv5tjgWwdy9W9UFqHXMNF1YfAOqvV/esHOF8pZR3WUAuXk7O4MhpWiIMKx74crrr2P9ojpPjKZJWojIBO1IVXOq/WTKrmUqFP7zgqCs4EqDVS8huDiIykQLB50NrFOE6XkzWpVkfBJk/7BY1X87168aLwB)

`(count "  ")` evaluates to `2`, so this function implements \$\lceil \dfrac a{2\pi b} \rceil\$.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic (83 series), 12 bytes

```
-int(-Tmax⁻¹min(e^(ΔList(ln(Ans
```

Takes input as a list of radius and distance in `Ans`: for example, `{0.9999:12.5663:prgmX`.

`e^(ΔList(ln(Ans` will take the ratio of those distances, and `min(` turns this into a number. Then we divide by `Tmax`, which is a graphing parameter that's equal to 2π by default. Finally, `-int(-` takes the ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 28 bytes

```
INPUT D,R?CEIL(D/(R+R)/PI())
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Intel 8087 FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8087) assembly, 22 bytes

```
; input: D,R (shortreal,shortreal)
; output: O (memsixteen)
FDIST   MACRO  D, R, O
    FLD  D      ; ST[] = D
    FLDPI       ; ST[] = PI
    FDIV        ; ST = D / PI
    FLD  R      ; ST[] = R
    FLD  ST     ; ST[] = R
    FADD        ; ST = R + R
    FDIV        ; ST = D / PI / R + R
    FISTP O
        ENDM
```

Uses only the Intel Eighty-Eighty-Seven math-coprocessor.  Inputs Distance (D) and Radius (R) as thirty-two bit IEEE Seven-Fifty-Four single-precision real. Returns O as a sixteen bit unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->d,r{d/=Math::PI*(r+r);d.ceil}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcq9DoIwFAXgvU9xR39qhSKomLo7mLhXBqQlkBggpR2M@OzVgnXwTOd@9yhze9iSXe3qKLB6ijU757pK08tpMVNLNT8IUsj6/rIc8TDAMCX0hWYY8fjn1JfN6JTQSTbeI@cR8XdAgt1Yt85DSuIkibDz/SfY7VFGZF5UIFoYRN3rvCkkBpWL2vQYWqM7owcE0EHJ//8ZMPadINkI@wY)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `cursors`, 18 bytes

```
[ / pi pi + up/i ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY49C8IwFEX3/Iq7C2mafqAVOyoOKihO4hCCxQxtQpIOUvrbY7RSL48L5yzvNkJ6bcP1sj/uKrTCP79Fpe6cF513MPbh/ctY1XkI57R0WJPt@XSoIHvrtHXY1OhNoqInA0HMgJQhxfiDgoH/gVPOkc@c0RyMsuUsUk6LssyiXMVEPZJwQwKjPreYXt1DM62pW2FAwxs)

Divide the distance by the radius, then ceiling-integer-divide that by 2pi. The ceiling-integer-division word `up/i` is provided by the `cursors` vocabulary.